# "hiding" \par from a tabular

Tags: tables, expl3, xparse

I want to use a macro to write a line of a tabular. As part of this macro, there is an argument that isn't set in the tabular, but is saved for later use. This unused argument should be allowed to contain `\par`. But as the following example shows, the tabular breaks when it encounters the `\par` (or in this case, the two newlines.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddTalk}{mmm}{
  \tl_new:c {l_#1_title_tl}
  \tl_set:cn {l_#1_title_tl} {#2}
  \tl_new:c {l_#1_abstract_tl} 
  \tl_set:cn {l_#1_abstract_tl} {#3}
  #2 & #1 \\
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \AddTalk{foo}{This is the title}{This is the abstract}
  \AddTalk{bar}{Another title}{Another abstract}
  \AddTalk{spock}{A breakage}{This abstract
%
  contains a paragraph break.}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(Remove the commented out linebreak to see the failure.)

So my question is this: How can I "hide" the contents of the unused argument of `\AddTalk` from the `tabular`? Or more generally, is there a better way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: Just make the argument of `\AddTalk` long: `\NewDocumentCommand{\AddTalk}{mm+m}{ ... }`

Comment: @cgnieder Aha! I totally missed that paragraph in the `xparse` doc. Could you turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah no wait. When I later "use" the unused argument, the linebreak has gone and has been replaced by `"par`. I guess I also want to make the unused argument unexpanded...

Comment: that seems unrelated to the MWE. If I simply use `\l_spock_abstract_tl` from your example the paragraph break is where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Yes this was a problem that I was using `\tl_to_str:c` to get at the abstract. If I use `\use:c` instead I get the right behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: Semantically better would be `\tl_use:c`

Comment: @cgnieder That's available after `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_use:N {c}`

Comment: @Seamus `\tl_to_str:c` is really *not* the correct way to handle it.

Comment: @egreg according to [interface3](http://texdoc.net/pkg/interface3) it is already part of the kernel

Comment: @cgnieder I didn't check; however, in case of doubts, using `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` will not do anything different than what's expected.

Comment: @egreg yes, that's true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not the `{tabular}`. The arguments of a command defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` (and with the other `xparse` commands) are short per default and hence choking on `\par`. One needs to make them long explicitly by preceding the argument identifier with `+`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddTalk}{mm+m}{ ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the problem of long arguments, your code has a big weakness: your assignments to token list variables are local, so they'll disappear as soon as the next `&` is scanned, that is, almost immediately.

You should do global assignments and probably building property list variables is better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddTalk}{ m m +m }
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_talks_#1_prop }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_talks_#1_prop } { title } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_talks_#1_prop } { abstract } { #3 }
  #2 & #1 \\
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\gettitle} { m }
 {
  \prop_get:cn { g_talks_#1_prop } { title }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getabstract} { m }
 {
  \prop_get:cn { g_talks_#1_prop } { abstract }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \AddTalk{foo}{This is the title}{This is the abstract}
  \AddTalk{bar}{Another title}{Another abstract}
  \AddTalk{spock}{A breakage}{This abstract

  contains a paragraph break.}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent\textbf{\gettitle{spock}:} \getabstract{spock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd already noticed the local thing. I didn't know about property lists. I will explore. Thanks!

Comment: `\prop_get:cnN` puts it in a token list. So the `\gettitle` macro needs to use something like `\l_tmpa_tl` and then `\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl`, right?

Comment: @Seamus My macros use `\prop_get:cn`, not `\prop_get:cnN`

Comment: Yes, I hadn't noticed the `\prop_get:cn` macro in the candidate additions section of `interface3`...